# How to use 像…似的?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, comparison

Can someone explain me the comparison structure 像 … 似的?

Why in this sentence there is 得 after 红？

> 他脸红得苹果似的

Couldn't I have said this instead?

> 他的脸红像苹果似的

Is there a pattern/scheme that I can follow, so that it is clearer to me?
Thank you.

Comment: 像 can be used as follows 像NP一样+adjective e。g。像苹果（玫瑰、鲜血）一样红  for more examples see iciba

Comment: 他的脸（非常、很）红，像（是）苹果似的 seems possible， cf。鸡蛋煮得太老了，像胶皮似的，吹来阵阵暖风,使人感到就像是春天似的， 似： <动> be similar ； look like ； seem ； appear <副>（似乎） it seems ； as if，example with 像VP似 used as 状语：他在赛跑中简直像飞 似 地绕着跑道跑， all examples from iciba

Comment: (looks, feels, sounds, smalls...) as same as... 像...似的

Answer (score 1):

"得" is often used after adjectives in Chinese language. Because "红" is adjective, so there is "得" after "红". For example, "她们两个人好得像一个人似的".

Answer (score 0):

得 is a particle, it links a verb to a following adverb. So you have

他-脸红-得-苹果-似的

He-blush-得-apple-seems like 的

He blushed red as an apple.

We will leave aside the fact that some apples are green!

Answer (score 0):

得 is a particle that introduces the complement of state. It is used after verbs or adjectives, and roughly means "in a way that".

他脸红得像苹果似的。His face became red 'in a way' that it looked like an apple.

You can't take the 得 off the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, 得（it is read softly as "de"）is a structural auxiliary word. It is used behind adjective for indicate the relationship between "he's face' "and "the apple". 
For another example like this condition:
她的笑容美得像花。( Her smile is sweaty, flower is also beautiful, and if you want to get them together,to build a relationship, you need use 得 connect them.)     Wish to help you:)